# Complete, single book of Peanuts comics?

Tags: identification-request, comics

While in a Barnes & Noble in the US during our recent holiday (December 2017), I came across a very large and very heavy book (possibly dark red in colour) containing a number of Peanuts comics. I believe it was every strip published from the 50s up until the end in 2000, because I checked the first and last pages to make sure.

I intended to take a photo of it or write down the ISBN so I could purchase it back home (it was too heavy to bring back), but my phone was flat so I wasn't able to.

Now looking on B&N and Amazon, I can't seem to find the book. I can find the individual volumes (e.g. 1950-1952) but not the single, large book that I saw.

Does anyone know the book I'm referring to?

Comment: Voting to leave open as this not a recommendation question. It is looking for a single book (almost like a story-id).

Comment: "*but my phone was flat so I wasn't able to*" - smartphones often are pretty flat, unlike the much chunkier older phones.

Comment: Have you tried calling the particular store you saw it at?

Comment: @Ovi, the thought didn't occur to me, however I've since bought the "Celebrating Peanuts" book. On top of which our phone doesn't allow international calls, so it's a bit tricky :)

Comment: Ah okay. Well maybe email could have been something to try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nearly 18,000 Peanuts strips were published in the newspapers, so a single volume would run to about 3,000 pages even if you managed to squeeze six strips on a page.  Needless to say, no such single volume exists.  As kimchi lover notes, there is a 26-volume set that contains all the strips (plus some "extras"), but this doesn't sound like what you saw.

My best guess is that you saw [*Celebrating Snoopy*](http://aaugh.com/wordpress/2017/08/review-celebrating-snoopy/), which matches your description of a large, dark red volume.  It is 10" by 13" and runs to 560 pages, and it came out just a few months ago.  Obviously, it doesn't contain all the strips, but it contains a lot of them.  If you want as many strips as possible in a single volume, either this book or the companion volume *Celebrating Peanuts* (which came out in hardcover at the 60th anniversary in 2010 and in softcover at the 65th anniversary in 2015) is your best bet.

Comment: Yep, that's the one! I thought it was the whole set because it was 500+ pages long, very large in size and looking at the first and last strips, they were the actual first and last strips. The book is now on its way. Thanks!